# Using JavaScript's eval() with multiple dependent functions

Tags: javascript, eval

How do I load dynamic dependencies into an `eval()` call? (If at all possible)

I am trying to run a call to `eval()` using multiple functions but I can't seem to get it to work. ie:

```
function foo() {
    return bar;
}

function foo2() {
    return foo();
}
```

Ideally, what I want to work is:

```
eval("
    (function() { 
        function foo() {
            return bar;
        }

        return foo(); 
     }())
");
```

But I keep getting an error that `foo is not defined`.

I know that if `foo()` is defined in the html of my page, then I can use `eval()` to write a function that is basically `foo2()` and get the result I want:

```
eval("
    (function() { 
        return foo(); 
     }())
");
```

But I want to be able to change both functions and still be able to call `foo2()` which will always reference `foo()`. Is this possible? What are some ways I could get this working?

Comment: Why are you trying to use `eval()`? You may have heard this before, but its use is almost always discouraged.

Comment: **eval** is **evil**!

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein I have heard it before. I am using it to run user entered javascript and then evaluate it's return values. Basically a very simple programming contest like software without the contest part

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein I am also taking steps to make sure that the user entered JS will not be able to be sent to anyone else. The code a user writes isn't shareable unless they manually copy it.

Comment: I didn't understand the last part can you explain more!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir see goal at the bottom of the post. Does that help? Im open to using whatever is easiest and I don't care if it isn't eval

Comment: Still didn't get it! Can you post an example?

Comment: "*I can't seem to get it to work*" - please post the exact code you are using, the input strings you are entering to be evaled, and the errors you are getting.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir added an example, the issue is in the last block with the variable `result` getting the proper value since I need to somehow include the user's code.

Comment: @Chris the code you posted with `numTestCases` is an abuse of `eval`, you just should define `CodeXample` as an array. There is no dynamic code in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try and type this into the textarea:

```
function hello(name) {
  alert("hello" + name);
}
```

Then `func` will be a reference to `hello` (`func == hello`). Then you can use `func` to test the testcases like it was `hello` for example.

```js
var ta = document.getElementById("code");

function run() {
  var code = "(function() { return " + ta.value + "; })()"; // code that will return a reference to the function typed by the user
  
  var func = eval(code); // func will be the function the user typed in the textarea
  
  func("me"); // you can call it like you want
}
```

```html
<textarea id="code"></textarea>
<button onclick="run()">Run</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up getting it working right before you posted. I really appreciate it though because I didn't know you could call functions outside the eval once they have been run through eval

Comment: @Chris `eval` will return the evaluated value of the code. Since the code will be an anounimous function that return a function, the return value of `eval` will be a reference to that function that you can use to test the test cases the way you want!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible, just make sure that your `eval`ed code overwrites the original functions with the new declarations, typically in the global scope.

Comment: I have tried pretty much any combination of adding 2 functions in a string form. usually I get an error "unexpected keyword 'function'" or something of the like. Does and eval call persist? i.e I call eval on a function, can I call that function outside the eval later? (possible through a call from another eval)

Comment: That sounds like a syntax error, from passing the wrong string. But yes, `eval` results persist, though of course the scope in which they get stored may vanish. `eval("a = 1"); eval("alert(a)")` works without problems.

Comment: I just realized I didn't try every possible combination. I kept leaving off the first '(' when building my eval query with 2 functions..........

Answer (score 0):

try to use the syntax
var foo = function(){} instead of function foo(){} in your eval, I don't know how you make multiline js string it doesn't exist, but an ";" beetween instruction for eval

Comment: Nah, that doesn't make any difference, though he needs to drop the IIFE

Comment: you code is working on my chrome it says bar is not defined but he use the new foo of the eval.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I found a way to do it. You have to have `\` at the end of each line and escape quotes:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
canvas.id = 'dailyTotalUsersCreated';
canvas.setAttribute('class', `bar dailyChart`)
var container = document.querySelector(`#daily`)
container.appendChild(canvas)
eval(` \
    var ${canvas.id} = new Chart('${canvas.id}', { \
        type: 'bar', \
        data: { \
            labels: [${lastSevenDays.map(obj => `"${new Date(obj.Date).toDateString()}"`)}], \
            datasets: [
                { \
                    label: 'Total Voice Users Created', \
                    data: [${lastSevenDays.map(obj => `${obj.Values.filter(obj => { return obj.Name === "Users Created" }).map(obj => totalUsersCreated - obj.Value)}`)}], \
                    backgroundColor: ['#3e95cd','#8e5ea2','#3cba9f','#e8c3b9','#c45850','#facb48','#384d3f','#247BA0','#F3FFBD','#FF1654'], \
                } \
            ] \
        }, \
        options: { \
            plugins: { \
                datalabels: { \
                    labels: { \
                        title: { \
                            color: 'black' \
                        } \
                    } \
                } \
            }, \
            scales: { \
                yAxes: [{
                    stacked: false,
                    gridLines: {
                        display: true,
                        color: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)"
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            } \
        } \
    }); \
`);
```